# What is the name of the language used in Windows batch files?

Tags: batch-file

What is the name of the language used in Windows batch files (*.BAT)?

Does it even *have* a name?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what made you think the language wasn't called "batch?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the language used in Batch files is just that: Batch.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file):

> A batch file is a kind of script file in DOS, OS/2 and Windows. It consists of a series of commands to be executed by the command line interpreter, stored in a plain text file.

Answer (score 1):

it's the command line interpreter of MS-DOS... like any other is a shell language MS-DOS one to be precise.

Comment: And its name is...? You haven't really answered the question here.

Comment: MS-DOS shell script.